# PySpark: TypeError: 'Row' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I used the following code to replace the `None` value in a DataFrame row to an empty string:

```
def replaceNone(row):
  row_len = len(row)
  for i in range(0, row_len):
    if row[i] is None:
      row[i] = ""    
  return row
```

in my pyspark code:

```
data_out = df.rdd.map(lambda row : replaceNone(row)).map(
  lambda row : "\t".join( [x.encode("utf-8") if isinstance(x, basestring) else str(x).encode("utf-8") for x in row])
)
```

Then I got the following errors:

```
File "<ipython-input-10-8e5d8b2c3a7f>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "<ipython-input-2-d1153a537442>", line 6, in replaceNone
TypeError: 'Row' object does not support item assignment
```

Does anyone have any idea about the error? How do I replace a "None" value in a row to an empty string? Thanks!

Comment: try `df.replace('None',' ')`.

Answer (score 6):

`Row` is a subclass of `tuple` and `tuples` in Python are immutable hence don't support item assignment. If you want to replace an item stored in a tuple you have rebuild it from scratch:

```py
## replace "" with placeholder of your choice 
tuple(x if x is not None else "" for x in row)
```

If you want to simply concatenate flat schema replacing null with empty string you can use `concat_ws`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import concat_ws

df.select(concat_ws("\t", *df.columns)).rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x)
```

To prepare output it makes more sense to use `spark-csv` and specify `nullValue`, `delimiter` and `quoteMode`.